# Can't open the file in the function in C by call pointer char

Tags: c

I can't open the file. The file is in the same C: drive. 
How can I fix this?

```
  void readTraceTxt(char* fichier, trace* uneTrace){
        int i = 0;
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(fichier,"r");
        if (fp == NULL)
            printf ("Error");
        else{
            fscanf(fp,"%s",uneTrace->comment);
            fscanf(fp,"%d",uneTrace->nbpts);
            for (int i = 0; i<uneTrace->nbpts; i++)
                fscanf(fp,"%f %f",uneTrace->time, uneTrace->value);
           }
        fclose(fp); } 

char str[] = "\"text.txt\"";
readTraceTxt(&str,&expeTrace);
```

Comment: When `fopen` fails, use `perror` to print the error message.  That will tell you *why* it failed.

Comment: the code looks OK. And it prints "Error " ? print `fichier` before feeding it to `fopen` And initialize `fp` with `NULL`.

Comment: lol didn't notice the bottom line.

Comment: I tried to use str[] = "text.txt", but it didn't run.

Comment: I modified some ways but all didn't run: if use (str[] = "text.txt"), when print the str: text.txt and (str[] = "\"text.txt\""), it print the str: "text.txt"

readTraceTxt(str,&expeTrace) and readTraceTxt(&str,&expeTrace); if remove the & in the function with paramettre str, there are the notification show:

The instruction at 0x7668ecc0 referenced memory at 0x0000000. the memory could be written. Click on ok to terminate the program